# [vb.net][Visual Studio] Force pivot table to refresh/recalculate

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a Ribbon for dev use. One of the items I want to add is how much time does a sheet recalculation take, so I can compare before and after doing some changes.
On the target sheet I have a pivot table.

How can I force a sheet recalculation? everithing I tried untill now does nothing.

```
Private Sub btlCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btlCalculate.Click
        'https://codesnippets.fesslersoft.de/measure-execution-time-of-a-action/

        'Dim time0 = Now()
        Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet

        With ListView1
            With .Items.Add(WB.Name)
                .SubItems.Add(WS.Name)
            End With
        End With

        Dim watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
            .CalculateFull()
            '.Calculate()
        End With
        watch.Stop()

        Dim intervalToMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
        'Dim time1 = Now()
        'Dim interval As TimeSpan = time1 - time0
        'Dim intervalToMs = interval.TotalMilliseconds

        With ListView1
            With .Items.Add(WS.Name)
                .SubItems.Add(intervalToMs)
            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work this out. It seems it was calculating the sheet (I teste using the `Randbetween` function, but it was not calculating the Pivot Table. I missed the fact that pivot table do not calculate automatically on sheet recalculation.

```
   Private Sub btlCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btlCalculate.Click
        'https://codesnippets.fesslersoft.de/measure-execution-time-of-a-action/

        'Dim time0 = Now()
        Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
        Dim AVG As Double, total As Double, I
        Dim PT As Excel.PivotTable

        Dim watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        On Error Resume Next

        If chkPivot.Checked Then
            For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
                PT.RefreshTable()
            Next
        Else
            WS.Calculate()
        End If


        watch.Stop()

        Dim intervalToMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
        'Dim time1 = Now()
        'Dim interval As TimeSpan = time1 - time0
        'Dim intervalToMs = interval.TotalMilliseconds

        With Me.DataGridView1
            Dim rowI As String() = New String() { .RowCount, WS.Name, intervalToMs, TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}
            .Rows.Add(rowI)

            For I = 0 To .Rows.Count - 2
                total += CDbl(.Rows(I).Cells(2).Value)
            Next

            AVG = total / (.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With

        txtAvg.Text = AVG

        On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub
```